# jQuery PHP Ajax Check User Logged in show modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have jQuery PHP Ajax to check user logged in or not.

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
setInterval(function()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'chkLoggedin.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success:function(response)
    {
        if(response == "sessionExpired")
        {
            bootbox.dialog(
            {
                message: "Please login to continue",
                title: "Not logged in",
                buttons:
                {
                    success:
                    {
                        label: "Log in",
                        className: "btn-success",
                        callback: function()
                        {
                            $('.bootbox').modal('hide');
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    }
});
}, 5000);
});
```

PHP

```
require("config/db.php");
session_start();
include("config/session.php");

if(empty($session))
{
    echo "sessionExpired";
}
```

I tried the above code is working, but after logout the modal show multipe until I refresh the page. I just want the modal show 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setTimeOut`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function instead of `setInterval`